# Looking for audio-book style CD ripper

Tags: windows, mp3, audiobook, m4a

I have a number of audio books on CD that I'd like to convert to MP3 (or M4A) format.  I'd prefer to have one large audio file per CD, with chapter marks at the track boundaries.

Almost all the CD ripping software I can find is designed for music CDs; is there something out there that can do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the chaptermarks [bonkencoder](http://www.bonkenc.org/) will do it.

Comment: I tried this out, and it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could rip the tracks to raw PCM (not WAV, which has headers etc) and just concatenate the files before encoding. This wouldn't give you chapter marks though.

Why not just use a player which can handle playing several files sequentially (as I think almost all players can)?

Comment: Well, audiobooks tend to be spread across a dozen CDs or so.  I'd rather manage 12 large MP3s rather than a hundred or so files.  (Also, audio books aren't always 1 chapter/disk or chapter/track.)

Answer (score 0):

Rip your audio books, then use **[MakeitOne MP3 Album Maker](http://www.makeitone.net/audio/mp3albummaker.htm)** pack/join your MP3 files in a single file - whilst still allowing full playability, tag editing and unpacking.

[image]

Unlike similar programs MakeitOne MP3 Album Maker allows you to join the MP3 files and unpack them back to their original state without loosing quality.

*MakeitOne MP3 Album Maker is freeware.*